# Update the viewed counter asynchronously

Tags: feature-request

The "viewed" counter to the right of a question is not updated asynchronously via AJAX. Users have to press F5 to refresh the window to see the latest value.

There are a number of counters that are updated asynchronously, such as the vote counter.  Could this also be included among them?

Answer (score 7):

The view count is tied to several expensive metrics that make it not feasible to perform well while being live updated. [*Would you like to know more?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224165/178816) (This addresses profile views, but the approach is the same for posts)

While some simpler sites will just show the count of requests for a page or resource, Stack Overflow ensures that views are only counted once per user.

In addition to that process, there is no actual problem presented by having to manually refresh in order to see the view counter change.

As a result, it is not worthwhile to have a live updating counter there.

Comment: "...there is no actual problem presented by having to manually refresh..." Indeed, there is. The density of initial views of a question, reflects the probability of it's being answered. So just `ALT+TAB`, for windows, or `CTRL+TAB` will be a little support to prospect if the OP will get answer in short time or not.

Comment: @sємsєм Interesting. Do you have any data to back that?

Comment: @Laurel It is just availabe usability scenario.

Comment: @sємsєм For feature requests, we generally want to see more justification for it than just "I want it" or "It makes life better". This includes data. See the tag wiki, namely *Your question should contain the details of your proposal, including a **justification of why the new feature is needed** and/or how it can improve the community. Basically, prove to the administration that they should spend time developing your feature.* (emphasis mine).